# Obtain user form input and display elsewhere in website elementor

Tags: forms, field, elementor

I'm simply trying to get a value that a user has inputted into a field in a elementor form and display it elsewhere in the website. I have tried several suggestions from chat GPT but to no avail unfortunately. It seems like such a simple task.

i tried using some java script suggested by chat GPT in the snippets plugin i think. i also tried some code , again suggested by chat gpt, using the shortened block coding. but again, this didn't work.